# JS: How can I add items to an new Objects array, instantiated from a constructor?

Tags: javascript, constructor

I am using a constructor function, that has an array, as such:

```
function Person(first, last, siblings) {
    this.firstName = first;
    this.lastName = last;
    this.siblingsArr = [];
}
```

I would like to pass items into the silbingsArr array when I am creating an object with that constructor function, eg:

```
var john = new Person('John', 'Smith', ['Joe', 'Steve', 'Mary']);
```

But this doesn't seem to work - the array for john remains empty.

What is the correct way of achieving this?

Comment: `this.siblingsArr = []` – You are assigning an empty array to `this.siblingsArr`, and you're ignoring the `siblings` parameter entirely…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `this.siblingsArr = siblings;` in the `Person`

```js
function Person(first, last, siblings) {
    this.firstName = first;
    this.lastName = last;
    this.siblingsArr = siblings;
}

var john = new Person('John', 'Smith', ['Joe', 'Steve', 'Mary']);
console.log(john);
```

Comment: Ah, I thought you had to instantiate the array in the constructor.

Comment: @MeltingDog no you don't. You just need to assign that. Glad to help you :)